# How to get pictures from QWebView

Tags: c++, image, qt, qwebview

Does anybody know how to get a picture from qwebview? My situation is, there is no scope to use the image url and then a QNetworkRequest. I just need to 'extract' the image from the QWebview.

Comment: What do you mean with "get a picture"? Getting a screenshot of the page? A screenshot of a portion of the page? Downloading an image contained in the DOM?

Comment: I want to get an image which is in the view. For example, the image of <img src="path" /> This image without redownloading it, just from the view. If it don't work, then screenshot of a portion will do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you need to get the `QWebElement` with the image you want to save - if you don't have it already, a good way to get it is

```
QWebElement el = view.page()->mainFrame()->findFirstElement("IMG[src='path/to/img'");
```

assuming `view` is the name of your `QWebView`. Then,

```
QImage image(el.geometry().width(), el.geometry().height(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
QPainter painter(&image);
el.render(&painter);
painter.end();
image.save("path/to/img.png");
```

Comment: `el.geometry().width(), el.geometry().height()` could be replaced with `el.geometry().size()`